# Find index of array within nested array javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to get the index of arrays that are present inside a nested array. I have written the below script but I am not getting the index of the array.

What am I missing?

```
const Data = [
     
      ["item 1", "item 1.1", "item 1.2", [543, 8329]],
      ["item 2", "item 2.2", "item 2.3", [3980, 56]],
      ["item 3", "item 3.3", "item 3.4", [64, 435]],
    
      
    ];
    
    const flist = [
         ["item 2", "item 2.2", "item 2.3", [3980, 56]],
         ["item 3", "item 3.3", "item 3.4", [64, 435]],
        ]
        
    let fl = [0, 2];

    flist.map((data) => {
       fl.push(Data.indexOf(data));
     });

    console.log(fl);
```

getting `[0, 2, -1, -1]`

Comment: You should use `forEach()` if you're not using the return values of the callback functions.

Comment: Okay, but how can I get the index of matching elements?

Comment: With `findIndex()`. It takes a callback function that can do the comparison.

Comment: Can you please show me an example

Comment: I gave you a link to another question that shows how to compare arrays.

Comment: Thank you but I am not able to connect these together i.e comparing and getting the index of arrays.

Comment: Show what you tried and I'll reopen the question to explain how to fix it. I'm not going to do your work for you.

Comment: I tried this   let res =  Data.length === flist.length && Data.every(function(value, index) { return value === flist[index]})   this gives false.

Comment: Please edit the question and show the whole code, including `Data.findIndex()`